# Rosbag: play on demand service

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get rosbag to publish the next message by calling a service.
A use-case is that a node request the rosbag player to publish the next message without a fixed hz, but when the node is ready to receive new info. This will allow for a lot of flexibility during the development of complex systems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56551/rosbag:-play-on-demand-service/) by [TRS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4314/trs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe this exists out-of-the-box.

[Rosbag command line tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#play) do allow you to play back topics at a modified (possibly very slow) constant rate with --rate.  If you want very strict control over the publishing, this code snippet should serve:

```
import roslib, rospy, rosbag
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

class BagByService(object):
    def __init__(self, bagfile):
        self.bag = rosbag.Bag(bagfile, 'r')
        self.message_generator = self.bag.read_messages()
        self.next_msgs_srv = rospy.Service('/next_msg', Empty, self.pub_next_msg)

        #Create a publisher for each topic
        self.publishers = {}
        for con in self.bag._get_connections():
            msg_class = roslib.message.get_message_class(con.datatype)
            self.publishers[con.topic] = rospy.Publisher(con.topic, msg_class)

    def pub_next_msg(self, req):
        topic, msg, time = self.message_generator.next()
        self.publishers[topic].publish(msg)

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    rospy.init_node('bag_by_service')
    bbs = BagByService(sys.argv[1])
    rospy.spin()
```

Run this with the .bag file as the only commandline argument. Calling the Empty '/next_msg' service will publish the next message in the bag file.  Clearly, more interesting things could be done from here (filtering by time, topic, etc.)

---

Originally posted by [pgrice](https://answers.ros.org/users/235/pgrice/) with karma: 196 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martinakos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36215/martinakos/) on 2019-06-20**:
pub_next_msg() needs to return a response, otherwise a "service handler returned None" error occurs.
I add:  `return EmptyResponse()`   at the end of pub_next_msg()  which requires a `from std_srvs.srv import EmptyResponse` and that solves the problem